# afnetworking post to local host works using curl

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am using afnetworking 2.0 to do a post. Using the google app postman, I am able to post just fine, however when using afnetworking I get the following error:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo=0x10d5f6270 {NSUnderlyingError=0x10ed45a80 "unsupported URL", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=localhost:5000/api/createNewTenant, NSErrorFailingURLKey=localhost:5000/api/createNewTenant, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL}
```

Does AFNetworking not support localhost? Here is my afnetworking code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"email" : self.emailField.text,
                                 @"message" : self.message.text };
    [manager POST:@"localhost:5000/api/createNewTenant" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Comment: I think you need the http:// in front of localhost.

Comment: And obviously, that might work on simulator, but not device.